REG ADD Gives errors, contains ( ) "" % & -If -Command
I have Searched StackOverflow and i am unable to find anything remotely related to this specific issue.  please do not delete my question.  IF there is a question already existing on this website that has this info PLEASE SHARE a link.  THANKS
I am new to poweshell commands and scripting altogether.  I am able to locate MOST of my powershell questions online but this one is giving me grief.  I am trying to REG ADD a registry key, when i try to add the actual key that contains quotes "",  Ampersands &, parentheses ( ), Percent %,  a -IF. AND a -COMMAND in the reg value, I get the error that says ERROR: Invalid syntax.
If i try to shorten the reg value i get other errors (paraphrasing here) At line:1 char:15 yada yada Unexpected token -command -If in expression or statement
If someone would be so kind as to point out and/or correct the error in my command i would be most appreciative of the help.
The command is as follows:
REG ADD HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"

the value of of the REG_SZ is supposed to be "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
Including the beginning and ending quotes.  I have tried multiple quotes to encapsulate the quote in more quotes with no success.  if i change the expected value to anything else such as simple words, ie. ZOMBIE, it works but any portion of the value that has "-Command" "if" or "%1" throws an error.  REG ADD /? offers help for most stuff that i have been able to use to add multiple entries to the reg but this has me scratching my head.
Thanks in advance for any info.  I have a whole bunch of entries to add to my reg and this is just the beginning.
